# Catholicism and the Laws of Moses

Tags: catholicism, tithe

> The Catholic Church teaches that the Law of Moses (the Old Law) is a
>   preparation for the Gospel, and as such no longer binding. The New Law
>   (the Law of Gospel) is a perfection of it, given through faith in
>   Christ.

**Catechism of the Catholic Church, Second edition. Paragraphs 577-582 and 1950-1986**. http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/ccc_toc2.htm

Why does the Catholic church still require Tithing?

Comment: Related: [Do Catholics tithe?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/14388/do-catholics-tithe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't. There is no point where you are required to donate any amount of money. That's just silly. This is largely because a strict tithing rule is bordering on Pharisaic – someone in absolute poverty should not be required to

On the other hand *charity* is a requirement. Now, charity does not mean a gift of moneys, though that helps, rather it means a gift of self (close to the concept of agape in Greek). This is why you have quotes like this in the Catechism (p. 1974, emphasis mine):

> The evangelical counsels manifest the **living fullness of charity**, which is *never satisfied* with not giving more. They attest its vitality and call forth our spiritual readiness. ***The perfection of the New Law consists essentially in the precepts of love of God and neighbor***. The counsels point out the more direct ways, the readier means, and are to be practiced in keeping with the vocation of each:

Comment: Have you got evidence that the Pharisees enforced a strict tithing law? If so what? I have only been able to find New Testament deduction and speculation. If there was such a law how was it enforced? Who enforced it? What was the punishment for failing to tithe? Was this similar to buying indulgences?

Comment: @gideonmarx "Pharisaic" does not necessarily mean "the Pharisees did it" (though I'm reasonably sure they did). A secondary meaning is *Hypocritically self-righteous and condemnatory.* (see http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pharisaic)